# Polling satellite data from Android GPS in a battery efficient way

Tags: android, gps, location, battery, satellite

This is a very close question to lots of other questions out there (i.e. [Android Regular GPS Polling in Service, maximizing battery life](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522154/android-regular-gps-polling-in-service-maximizing-battery-life)). However, what I need is quite different.

So, basically im looking for a way to regularly poll Android devices using the `LocationManager` class. Specifically, I want the SATELLITE information (NOT the Location itself). I.e. I just want the number of satellites, the signal-to-noise ratio and so on. I am looking to do this in the most battery efficient way possible.

One way to do it is to get the satellite information using the `onGpsStatusChanged` callback, and then getting the satellites with something like `location_manager.getGpsStatus(null).getSatellites()`. This is indeed, how I am doing it.

Relating to this now, I have a few questions that I cannot find anywhere in the Android documentations or in any forum online i've seen!

1. Will `onGpsStatusChanged` be called without adding a `LocationListener` to my `LocationManager`? Can I just somehow query the GPS receiver to send me the satellite info without registering a LocationListener as well? I.e. Is there a direct way of doing it other than something like:

   ```
           location_manager.addGpsStatusListener(gps_status_listener_);
           location_manager.requestLocationUpdates(location_manager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).getName(), 3000, 2f, location_listener_);
   ```

   Because for me, the `LocationListener` is useless.
2. Is it more battery efficient to attach the `GPSStatusListener` periodically, get satellite info and remove the listener OR just attach it once and keep polling until a certain period where I don't need it anymore. I realize continuous polling is battery inefficient and most of the questions out there deal with polling the `LocationManager` with `requestLocationUpdates` and setting minTime and minDistance etc. to minimize the amount of battery consumed. However, I only need the satellite information, so maybe there is a way to poll continuously without this consumption of battery?
3. This leads right into my next question which is: How quickly does the `GPSStatusListener` get the satellite info on average. I realize getting a LOCATION takes a while and depends on the Providers and LastKnownLocation and yada yada. But what about the satellite info? Is it quicker?

If anyone can help me out here, I would be highly obliged! Thank you in advance all!